# Microsoft Server 2008 r2 php odbc connection not working

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc, windows-server-2008

I recently moved my server over to server 2008 r2 from server 2008, and now my php based website cannot connect to the database. The database is a .accdb and worked fine on the old operating system, I set the database as a system dns. My php page is not returning any errors, but it wont connect to the dns. Is there any way i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you install the [Access 2010 Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) on the server, if the full version (or the runtime) of Access 2007/2010/2013 is not installed on the server, you must install the database engine or you will never be able to open `.accdb` databases.

Also make sure that your whole environment is set to work in 32 bits, or 64 bits, but not a mix, you can't install the 32bit *and* 64bit version on the same server.

Easiest is probably to stick to 32bits and make sure your php server is set for 32bits, also make sure that your [ODBC DSN is 32bits](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/03/16/32-bit-odbc-on-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx).

Comment: I have done all those thing, and i still have the same problem. :(

Comment: @Grant have you tried to make sure that the DSN you created actually works? Try to connect to it from another application, like [SqlDbx](http://www.sqldbx.com/) and make sure you can access the data correctly. If that works, then your issue is with your PHP/odbc layer. Show your code so we can see how you are connecting to the database and accessing your data from PHP.